# SDN5: Found more than one matching @RelationshipEntity for (14762)-[CONTAINS]->(14781) but cannot tell which one to use

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm, spring-data-neo4j-5, spring-data-neo4

I have created two different Spring Data Neo4j 5 `@RelationshipEntity` with the same type:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "CONTAINS")
public class CharacteristicRelationship {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private CharacteristicGroup characteristicGroup;

    @EndNode
    private Characteristic characteristic;

}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "CONTAINS")
public class DecisionGroupRelationship {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Decision decision;

    @EndNode
    private DecisionGroup childGroup;

}
```

everything is working fine and I'm successfully able to pass all my tests but right now I continuously getting the following errors in the console:

```
2018-04-29 15:36:52.387 ERROR 7664 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper  : Found more than one matching @RelationshipEntity for (14762)-[CONTAINS]->(14781) but cannot tell which one to use
2018-04-29 15:36:52.390 ERROR 7664 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper  : Found more than one matching @RelationshipEntity for (14762)-[CONTAINS]->(14779) but cannot tell which one to use
2018-04-29 15:36:52.391 ERROR 7664 --- [           main] org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper  : Found more than one matching @RelationshipEntity for (14762)-[CONTAINS]->(14774) but cannot tell which one to use
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ? Does it allowed to have different `@RelationshipEntity` with the same types ?

at `org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.getRelationshipEntity(Edge)` I can see the following code:

```
} else {
    // almost definitely a user bug
    logger.error("Found more than one matching @RelationshipEntity for {} but cannot tell which one to use",
    edge.toString());
 }
```

that just prints the error log and that's it. It is really hard to understand from this - it is a bug or no and how to deal with it.

The classes:

```
@NodeEntity
public class CharacteristicGroup extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";
    private static final String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    @Index(unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private String name;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private String lowerName;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<DecisionGroup> decisionGroups;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<CharacteristicRelationship> characteristicRelationships;

...

}

@NodeEntity
public class Characteristic extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    @Index(unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private String name;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private String lowerName;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<CharacteristicProperty> properties;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<CharacteristicRelationship> characteristicRelationships;

...

}

@NodeEntity
public class DecisionGroup extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String CONTAINS_DECISION_GROUP = "CONTAINS_DECISION_GROUP";

    @Index(unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private String name;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private String lowerName;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS_DECISION_GROUP, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<DecisionGroupRelationship> decisionGroupRelationships;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private int totalChildDecisions;

...

}

@NodeEntity
public class Decision extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";
    private static final String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private static final String CONTAINS_DECISION_GROUP = "CONTAINS_DECISION_GROUP";
    public static final String FOLLOWS = "FOLLOWS";

    @Index(unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private String name;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private String lowerName;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<DecisionGroup> parentGroups;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS_DECISION_GROUP, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<DecisionGroupRelationship> childGroupRelationships;

    @Relationship(type = DEFINED_BY, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Media> medias;

    @Index(unique = false)
    private int totalViews;

...

}

@NodeEntity
public abstract class BaseEntity implements BaseEntityVisitable {

    private static final String CREATED_BY = "CREATED_BY";
    private static final String UPDATED_BY = "UPDATED_BY";
    private static final String OWNED_BY = "OWNED_BY";
    private static final String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long graphId;

    @Index(unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    @Index(unique = true)
    private String customId;

    @DateLong
    @Index(unique = false)
    private Date createDate;

    @Relationship(type = CREATED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private User createUser;

    @DateLong
    @Index(unique = false)
    private Date updateDate;

    @Relationship(type = UPDATED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private User updateUser;

    @Relationship(type = OWNED_BY, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<BaseEntity> ownerEntities;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Translation> translations;

...

}
```

Comment: Please show the source code for `CharacteristicGroup`, `Characteristic`, `DecisionGroup`, and `Decision`.

Comment: @cmosher01 I have updated the question with the mentioned classes

Comment: by the way, I have fixed the issue by renaming the second relationship entity type into something unique(CONTAINS_DECISION_GROUP) but it is still interesting why it does not working normally with the same types.

Comment: Which data are you requesting and are you requesting it ?